# How to config log4j on yarn?

Tags: log4j, hadoop-yarn

Background: The yarn is installed by cloudera manager. I use yarn to run my xxx.jar.

I use yarn to run my xxx.jar. As we know, `syslog` file  will contain the log4j related logs. `stdout` file will contain some output like System.out.println(...). Blow is the some out put in `stdout` file:

```
===============================================================
LogType:stdout
LogLastModifiedTime:Sun Oct 11 21:19:27 +0800 2020
LogLength:109238
LogContents:
log4j: Trying to find [container-log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05.
log4j: Using URL [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-3.0.0-cdh6.3.2.jar!/container-log4j.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-3.0.0-cdh6.3.2.jar!/container-log4j.properties
log4j: Hierarchy threshold set to [ALL].
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO,CLA, EventCounter].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category root set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "CLA".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "CLA".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{ISO8601} %p [%t] %c: %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "CLA".
log4j: Setting property [containerLogFile] to [syslog].
log4j: Setting property [totalLogFileSize] to [1048576].
log4j: Setting property [containerLogDir] to [/yarn/container-logs/application_1602420941906_0002/container_1602420941906_0002_01_000001].
log4j: setFile called: /yarn/container-logs/application_1602420941906_0002/container_1602420941906_0002_01_000001/syslog, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "CLA" options.
log4j: Parsing appender named "EventCounter".
log4j: Parsed "EventCounter" options.
log4j: Parsing for [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce] with value=[INFO,CLA].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "CLA".
log4j: Appender "CLA" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce=[false]
log4j: Setting additivity for "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce" to false
log4j: Parsing for [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger] with value=[INFO,CLA].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "CLA".
log4j: Appender "CLA" was already parsed.
log4j: Handling log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger=[false]
log4j: Setting additivity for "org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger" to false
log4j: Finished configuring.
Launcher AM configuration loaded
```

From the log, we can see the log4j properties is from `jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-3.0.0-cdh6.3.2.jar!/container-log4j.properties`. I alse download the `hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-3.0.0-cdh6.3.2.jar`. the content of `container-log4j.properties` is:

```
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
#
# Define some default values that can be overridden by system properties
hadoop.root.logger=DEBUG,CLA
yarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.logger=${hadoop.root.logger}

# Define the root logger to the system property "hadoop.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${hadoop.root.logger}, EventCounter

# Logging Threshold
log4j.threshold=ALL

#
# ContainerLog Appender
#

#Default values
yarn.app.container.log.dir=null
yarn.app.container.log.filesize=100

log4j.appender.CLA=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ContainerLogAppender
log4j.appender.CLA.containerLogDir=${yarn.app.container.log.dir}
log4j.appender.CLA.containerLogFile=${hadoop.root.logfile}
log4j.appender.CLA.totalLogFileSize=${yarn.app.container.log.filesize}
log4j.appender.CLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p [%t] %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.CRLA=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ContainerRollingLogAppender
log4j.appender.CRLA.containerLogDir=${yarn.app.container.log.dir}
log4j.appender.CRLA.containerLogFile=${hadoop.root.logfile}
log4j.appender.CRLA.maximumFileSize=${yarn.app.container.log.filesize}
log4j.appender.CRLA.maxBackupIndex=${yarn.app.container.log.backups}
log4j.appender.CRLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CRLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p [%t] %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.shuffleCLA=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ContainerLogAppender
log4j.appender.shuffleCLA.containerLogDir=${yarn.app.container.log.dir}
log4j.appender.shuffleCLA.containerLogFile=${yarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.logfile}
log4j.appender.shuffleCLA.totalLogFileSize=${yarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.log.filesize}
log4j.appender.shuffleCLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.shuffleCLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p [%t] %c: %m%n

log4j.appender.shuffleCRLA=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ContainerRollingLogAppender
log4j.appender.shuffleCRLA.containerLogDir=${yarn.app.container.log.dir}
log4j.appender.shuffleCRLA.containerLogFile=${yarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.logfile}
log4j.appender.shuffleCRLA.maximumFileSize=${yarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.log.filesize}
log4j.appender.shuffleCRLA.maxBackupIndex=${yarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.log.backups}
log4j.appender.shuffleCRLA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.shuffleCRLA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %p [%t] %c: %m%n

################################################################################
# Shuffle Logger
#
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce=${yarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce=false
# Merger is used for both map-side and reduce-side spill merging. On the map
# side yarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.logger == hadoop.root.logger
#
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger=${yarn.app.mapreduce.shuffle.logger}
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Merger=false
#
# Event Counter Appender
# Sends counts of logging messages at different severity levels to Hadoop Metrics.
#
log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter
```

So, i think the log4j related log will be saved in `syslog` file. But after run my xxx.jar in yarn, there is nothing in syslog, my xxx.jar also contains some code like: `System.out.println("my demo");`. And i can find the output "my demo" in stdout after run my xxx.jar.

So my question is why the log4j related output cann't been printed out? Is there any other configuration needed?

Answer (score 0):

Got exactly same issue. (I use EMR-5.33, Oozie 5.2.0)

The logs are written to syslog if you set 0 to this property `log4j.appender.CLA.totalLogFileSize`
It gets the value from yarn.app.container.log.filesize config.

```
log4j.appender.CLA.totalLogFileSize=${yarn.app.container.log.filesize}
```

There is an Oozie ticket for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-3600